# With indices and without indices.

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms

Let $S = (S^{\mu\nu})$ be a two form on a four space and $\tilde S$ is the (Hodge) dual of $S$.

On what condition can we have

$$\partial_{\mu}(S^{\mu\nu}+\tilde{S}^{\mu\nu}) = 0\Leftrightarrow d(S+ \tilde S) = 0?$$

Comment: $d(S+\bar S)$ is a three form while $\partial_{\mu}(S^{\mu\nu}+\tilde{S}^{\mu\nu})$ is a one form, they are not equal.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say that $S^{\mu\nu}$ is a 2-form. Does it make any difference? I will edit the question right away.

Comment: That's the same problem... Do you mean $d^*$ instead of $d$?

Comment: No, but how would it make a difference if that was the case if you don't mind explaining.

Comment: I suppose $S$ is the two form given by $S = (S^{\mu\nu}$) (and similar for $\tilde S$)? Then by definition of $d$, $d(S +\tilde S)$ is a three form (with three indices). But now $\partial_{\mu}(S^{\mu\nu}+\tilde{S}^{\mu\nu})$ has only one indices ($\nu$), thus they are not even the same type of tensor.

Comment: On another thought, sometimes I see that $\partial_{\mu}N=A_{\mu}+\partial_{\mu}P$ and be written as $dN=A+dP$. Had my question been are $\partial_{\mu}(S^{\mu\nu}+\tilde{S}^{\mu\nu})=0$ and $d(S+\tilde{S})=0$ equal? Would this put us on a different track perhaps?

Comment: Will it happens that $*S = S$ and similar for $\tilde S$?

Comment: Sorry? Can you rephrase your question? I didn't quite understand.

Comment: But if you mean is $\tilde{S}$ the same thing as dual of S then yes.

Comment: By dual do you mean Hodge dual?

Comment: Yes, I do, it is a Hodge dual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using that $ \tilde S$ is the Hodge dual of $S$, we have

$$*(S + \tilde S) = (S+ \tilde S),$$

where $*$ is the Hodge star operator (Acting on two forms).

Then

$$\partial_{\mu}(S^{\mu\nu}+\tilde{S}^{\mu\nu}) = 0$$

if and only if $d^* (S+ \tilde S) = 0$, where $d^*$ is the adjoint of $d$. But $d^* = \pm *d*$, so the equality is the same as

$$0=d (*(S+ \tilde S)) = d(S+ \tilde S).$$

Comment: Ah great, it turned out that they are indeed equal. So, the trick was in setting this equal to zero, was it? Thank you John.